# Returning a value from 'success' block in JS (Azure Mobile Service)

Tags: javascript, function, azure, scope, return-value

I have a rather simple getUser method that I'm having some trouble with. I am not deeply familiar with scopes and such in JS so this is giving me a head ache. Basically I want to fetch an object from the database and return it to the calling method:

```
function getUser(uid)
{
    var result = null;

    var userTable = tables.getTable('Users');

    userTable.where({
        userId: uid
    }).read({
        success: function (results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                result = results[0];
                console.log('userid'+result.id);
            }
        }
    });
    console.log('userid-'+result.id); // undefined!!
    return result;
}
```

Also, returning from inside the success doesn't return from getUser, but just the function defined inside. I tried "result = function(results)" as well but it stores the defined function and not the return value.

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue! Hopefully this bumps it.

Comment: Hello, AR. I found a solution to this elsewhere. In practice (to the best of my understanding), it is not possible to do this within a JavaScript with asynchronous functions. What you need to do is create a recursion instead from inside the success handler.

Comment: I found the solution independently too. :) Posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this elsewhere. In practice (to the best of my understanding), it is not possible to do this within a JavaScript with asynchronous functions. What you need to do is create a recursion instead from inside the success handler.

Answer (score 0):

Because the call to the database is asynchronous, your last two lines are executed (and hence result is undefined) before the call the database actually finishes. So you need to handle everything inside your success callback. Or, if your `getUser()` func is a helper, you could structure your code (without recursion) like this with a callback:

```
function insertOrWhateverCallingMethod()
{
    var uid = 'blah';

    getUser(uid,function(user) {
        // Do something with the user object
    });

}

function getUser(uid,callback)
{
    var result = null;

    var userTable = tables.getTable('Users');

    userTable.where({
        userId: uid
    }).read({
        success: function (results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                result = results[0];
                console.log('userid'+result.id);
                callback(result);
            }
        }
    });
    callback(null);
}
```

The code above assumes you're in a table script, where the `tables` object is available - if it's not you can pass it as a parameter to `getUser()`.